# Capture cctv camera with iphone application using IP

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I want to develop a cctv camera app and I don't know what steps I need to take.
i have the data below for connecting cctv camera:

- Ip address
- port ID
- user name
- password

i checked live555 and RTMPStreamPublisher demo [from here](https://github.com/slavavdovichenko/MediaLibDemos/tree/master/RTMPStreamPublisher), but i don't know where I should start. i also read that i should use the ffmpeg framework.

What I want is an app similar to kView on [itunes](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/kview/id452625390?mt=8). This app is able to stream a cctv camera feed with the above configuration detials

Does anyone know what direction I need to go in? Is there a demo or open-source app that accomplishes this?

Answer (score -1):

i am not familar with ios development. Usually people build this kind of application base on ffmpeg. you can also try gstreamer.